# open pupop when select a tab react native

Tags: react-native, popup, react-native-tabnavigator

i'm new to react native and i want to have a tabNavigator that when 'Other' tab is selected a popup shows up . its my code but it don't recognize 'this' in 'ModalExample' class.
any help would be appreciated.

```
export const Tabs = TabNavigator({
    Notifications: {
        screen: Notifications,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="access-alarms" size={25} color={tintColor} />
        },
    },
    Home: {
        screen: Home,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="home" size={25} color={tintColor} />
        },
    },

    Other: {
        screen: ModalExample,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="more" size={25} color={tintColor} />
        },
    },
},
{
    tabBarOptions: {
        showIcon: true,
        showLabel: false,
        scrollEnabled: false
    },
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
});
```

and its other class:

```
export default class ModalExample extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.popupDialog.show();
}

render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <PopupDialog
                ref={(popupDialog) => { this.popupDialog = popupDialog; }}
            >
                <View>
                    <Text>Hello</Text>
                </View>
            </PopupDialog>
        </View>
    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand how you are using `<PopupDialog/>`. But i think [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html) link can help you with your requirement.